# mailx how to pipe the messages repeatedly through a command

Tags: shell, mailx

Operating system linux Ubuntu 16.04

Using mailx ( or other utility ) I need to pipe to a command the messages inside the mail box one by one repeatedly .

I try iteratively to execute once started mailx the command:

```
pipe . munpack
```

The above should mean "pipe the current message to the command munpack"

but it answers:

```
Pipe to: "munpack"
munpack: reading from standard input
Did not find anything to unpack from standard input
"munpack" 18224 bytes
```

If that worked, I don΄t know how to iterate ( instead of sending all the messages ).

Answer (score 0):

The pipe command pipes out only the first text part of the message, not all the message including the attachements.
So the munpack is not able to unpack and gives the misleading message above stated.
The way to do it is to use the write command inside mailx to save attachements and afterwards see what to do with them.